# How to connect UI to network libray which is connected to redis?

Tags: redis, redis-py, plotly-dash

I have this sever and client('Raspberry pis'). Now I have to read the sever and clients from redis db and get messages and show it in Frontend UI. I am using DASH frame work. How can I achieve application sever and read the live updates [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lyEtt.png)
Something like in this pic and I am not using celery and flask.

#### Server.py

```
import time

from mmnet.server import Server

BROKER = {"address": "10.0.10.1",
          "port": 6379,
          "db": 0}

# Create a new server instance. Pass it a dictionary with the connection details.
server = Server(BROKER)

# Tell the server which devices to expect. A combination of module + device is unique.
server.expect('Module1', 'Device1')

# The server waits for all expected devices to connect and calls their initialization function.
server.init()

# Execute a remote function in the given device with the given parameters. The result of
# this query will be returned by the function. This call is BLOCKING, so it will stop on the server
# until the function call finishes on the client
result = server.execute_function('Module1', 'Device1', 'move_to', 10, 50, 100, value=True, test="yes please")

# The server runs with a daemon thread, so make sure your program does not terminate!
try:
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass

# Always close the server at the end!
server.close()
```

#### Client.py

```
import time

from mmnet.client import Client

BROKER = {"address": "10.0.10.1",
          "port": 6379,
          "db": 0}


def move_to(x, y, z, value="abc", test="def"):
    return str(x) + str(y) + str(z) + value + test


def init_device():
    pass


# Create a new client instance
client = Client(BROKER, 'Module1', 'Device1')

# Register your available functions
client.register_action('move_to', move_to)

# Notify the server we are ready to be initialized
client.init(init_device)

# The clients runs with a daemon thread, so make sure your program does not terminate!
try:
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass

# Always close the client at the end!
client.close()
```